# No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public". function Ownable() {}

Tags: erc-20, contract-debugging

I'm trying to learn how to create tokens using Solidity/MIST.

I have modified a pre existing contract on a functioning token but I am having an error whenever I insert it into Ropsten.

The contract code can be seen here (it pasted oddly into stackexchange)

https://pastebin.com/s6Wc5wMp

The error i'm getting is:

```
 No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
function Ownable() {
^Spanning multiple lines.,
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a duplicate but I'll leave it to others to confirm that.

The error is really a warning. It's simply saying that no visibility was specified, so it's going with the default. This has been related to security issues in contracts - evidently, developers didn't realize their sensitive functions were open to "public". This error is added to more recent compilers to turn the dev's attention to a possible risk.

You can easily silence the warning by adding the modifier `public`:

```
function Ownable() public { ...
```

This won't change anything about the compiled code but it will signal the compiler that you are aware of the `public` visibility.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it safe to leave most things as public?

Comment: I think it's safer to say that visibility should be limited to those who should see it. It just happens that the most common use-case something users and contracts are supposed to see. Public functions are the most common. The Parity debacle is traceable to a public function that (arguably) should have been guarded better because a random user was permitted to execute something that caused some damage. This warning would have said "hey ... do you realize it's public?"

Comment: Thanks for the help Rob, i'm banging my head of the wall, do you have twitter? I've a few questions you could probably answer quickly. I'm @barryflood on twitter.

Comment: I got it working! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you are **not specifying visibility of the function**.

I suggest to read Solidity Documentation to understand [Function Types](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html?highlight=pure#function-types) and [Visibility and Getters](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?highlight=private#visibility-and-getters).

There are currently 4 function types:

- public  *- can be used both as an internal and as an external function.*
- internal *- can only be called inside the current contract.*
- external *- can be called from other contracts and via transactions.*
- private *- are only visible for the contract they are defined in and not in derived contracts.*

Comment: Thanks for this, i've added public to most things. I'm getting another error now though:

   function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    ^
Spanning multiple lines.
, 

what does that mean?

Comment: The same warning. Compiler suggests you to modify visibility of this function to `pure`. Just do it.

Comment: I've done this but keep running into more errors. I appreciate the help.

what does this mean?

Overriding function changes state mutability from "pure" to "view".
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    ^
Spanning multiple lines.

Comment: This one means that you need to change visibility from `pure` to `view`, because you are using external for this function variables, but not changing any stored data.

Comment: It already is set as view I think, unless i'm missing something?

unction balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance)

Comment: You should make small research and understand how visibility and function types work. If you will have new specific questions feel free to [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).